# How can I get all container the height of the highest?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have the following problem:
I want all my cols with the height of the highest.

Preferably only with HTML, CSS, SCSS.

**Infos:**

I used Bootstrap 3.

All of this elements have "height: 100%"

**Structure:**

I have an "Container-Fluid". Inside this is an row with 4 cols (nav, content, infobox and an empty col)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row myRowStyle">
        <!-- Logo, Search, Navbar -->
        <div class="col-md-2 navColorBack">
        </div>
        <!-- Header, Content -->
        <div class="col-md-6 contentColor">
        <div>
        <!-- Info Box -->
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 infoColor">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 emptyBox">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6TB2.png)

**What I have not done**

- I don't edit any Display argument because, this would crash my
  resizing.
- I haven't any float with exception of the Bootstrap styles.

**Snippet**

```css
html,body {
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;

  }
  
  h1,h2 {
    color: white;
  }

  h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  //Logo, Navbar, Search
  .container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
 }
 
    .row {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
 }
      .navColorBack {
        background-color: #dfdb00;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
  }

        .picture {
          width: auto;
          padding: 40px 10px 5px;
          background-color: white;
}
          .logo {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
          }

          .navbar-form {
            padding: 0px 0px;
}
            .marginSearch {
              margin: 80px 0px 0px;

            }

          .panel {
            border: 0px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
          }

          .navColor {
            background-color: #dfdb00;
          }

          .navColor:hover {
            background-color: #b4b00b;
          }

          .navColor:active {
            background-color: #D9D9D9;
            font-weight: bold;
          }

          .collapse.in {
            background-color: #dfdb00;
          }

          .list-group-item {
            border-color: transparent;
          }

          .list-group-item:first-child {
            border-radius: 0px;
          }

          .list-group-item:last-child {
            border-radius: 0px;
          }

          .list-group-item:hover {
            background-color: #b4b00b;
          }

          .list-group-item:active {
            background-color: #D9D9D9;
            font-weight: bold;
          }

          .subItemColor {
            background-color: #ccc80b;
            padding-left: 35px;
          }

          .floatIcon {
            float: right;
          }


      //Header, Content, Footer
      .contentColor {
        background-color: #D9D9D9;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
  }
  
        .header {
          height: 300px;
    }

          .headerPicture {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
          }

        .content {
          padding: 0px 15px 15px;
    }

          a:link {
            color: #333;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: underline;
          }
    
          a:visited {
            color: #333;
          }
    
          a:hover {
            color: #01408d;
          }
    
          a:active {
            color: #333;
          }

        .fixed {
          bottom: 0px;
          position: static;
    }

          .container {
            width: auto;
            background-color: #dfdb00;
            padding: 10px 130px;
}

            p {
              padding: 0px 60px 0px 0px;
              margin: 2px 0px 0px;
              float: left;
              font-size: 13px;
            }

            .footerLinks {
              margin-right: 30px;
              color: #333;
            }

      //Infobox
      .infoColor {
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        height: 100%;
  }
  
        a:link {
          color: #333;
          font-weight: bold;
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
  
        a:visited {
          color: #333;
        }
  
        a:hover {
          color: #01408d;
        }
  
        a:active {
          color: #333;
        }

        .infoBoxPicture {
          width: 100%;
        }

        .fa {
          color: #01408d;
        }

        .btnFacebook {
          border-radius: 20px;
          background-color: white;
          margin: 10px 0px 0px 130px;
        }

        .facebookText {
          margin: 5px 40px 0px;
        }

      .emptyBox {
        //background-color: #B3B3B3;
        background-color: rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.82);
        height: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Scss/color.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row myRowStyle">

        <!-- Logo, Search, Navbar -->
        <div class="col-md-2 navColorBack">
            <div class="picture">
                <img class="logo" src="../sunset1.jpg" alt="logo">

                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group add-on marginSearch">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>



            <div id="MainMenu">
                <div class="list-group panel">
                    <!-- First Level -->
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item navColor" data-parent="#MainMenu">Home</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item navColor" data-parent="#MainMenu">Menüpunkt2</a>
                    <a href="#demo3" class="list-group-item navColor" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Menüpunkt3<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down floatIcon"></span> </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
                        <!-- Second Level -->
                        <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item subItemColor" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Submenü1</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü1</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü2</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü3</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü4</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü5</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü6</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü7</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü8</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- First Level -->
                    <a href="#demo4" class="list-group-item navColor" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Kontakt</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Header, Content -->
        <div class="col-md-6 contentColor">

            <div class="header">
                <img class="headerPicture" src="../sunset1.jpg" alt="header">
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <h1>Willkommen</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod <a href="#">tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</a> aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et <a href="#">justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</a> Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                <h2>Über uns ...</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est <a href="http://www.loremipsum.de/">Lorem ipsum</a> dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod <a href="#">tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</a> aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer fixed">
                <div class="container">
                    <p>VorschauFirma TestSite0 e.V. - TestStraße.100 - 15640 Testland</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>Tel.: 00000 / 0000 - 0</p>
                    <p>Fax: 00000 / 0000 - 00</p><br />
                    <a href="#" class="footerLinks">E-Mail: test(at)testSeitetestBereich-Test.de</a><br />
                    <a href="#" class="footerLinks">Impressum</a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLinks">Datenschutz</a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLinks">AGBs</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <!-- Info Box -->
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 infoColor">
            <h3>Überschrift 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <h4>Überschrift 4</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt dolore magna <a href="#">aliquyam erat</a>, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            <h5>Überschrift 5</h5>
            <img class="infoBoxPicture" src="../sunset1.jpg" alt="picture">
            <h6>Überschrift 6</h6>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <button class="btn btnFacebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <p class="facebookText">Besuchen Sie uns auf Facebook</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 emptyBox">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row myRowStyle">
  <!-- Logo, Search, Navbar -->
        <div class="col-md-2 navColorBack">
  <!-- Header, Content -->
        <div class="col-md-6 contentColor">
  <!-- Info Box -->
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 infoColor">
  <div class="col-md-2 emptyBox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I see your CSS please ?

Comment: I would have use a display:table on container-fluid but yeah, bootstrap.

Comment: https://repl.it/NsLM in the css tab

Comment: Can you please make a short snippet example to us your problem?

Comment: @SilverSurfer Do you mean an screenshot ? Klick on "Example Imgage" :)

Comment: Check this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet

Answer (score 0):

you need to change this only container-fluid instead of container

```
<div class="footer fixed">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <p>VorschauFirma TestSite0 e.V. - TestStraße.100 - 15640 Testland</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>Tel.: 00000 / 0000 - 0</p>
                    <p>Fax: 00000 / 0000 - 00</p><br />
                    <a href="#" class="footerLinks">E-Mail: test(at)testSeitetestBereich-Test.de</a><br />
                    <a href="#" class="footerLinks">Impressum</a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLinks">Datenschutz</a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLinks">AGBs</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```css
html,body {
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;

  }
  
  h1,h2 {
    color: white;
  }

  h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  //Logo, Navbar, Search
  .container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
 }
 
    .row {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
 }
      .navColorBack {
        background-color: #dfdb00;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
  }

        .picture {
          width: auto;
          padding: 40px 10px 5px;
          background-color: white;
}
          .logo {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
          }

          .navbar-form {
            padding: 0px 0px;
}
            .marginSearch {
              margin: 80px 0px 0px;

            }

          .panel {
            border: 0px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
          }

          .navColor {
            background-color: #dfdb00;
          }

          .navColor:hover {
            background-color: #b4b00b;
          }

          .navColor:active {
            background-color: #D9D9D9;
            font-weight: bold;
          }

          .collapse.in {
            background-color: #dfdb00;
          }

          .list-group-item {
            border-color: transparent;
          }

          .list-group-item:first-child {
            border-radius: 0px;
          }

          .list-group-item:last-child {
            border-radius: 0px;
          }

          .list-group-item:hover {
            background-color: #b4b00b;
          }

          .list-group-item:active {
            background-color: #D9D9D9;
            font-weight: bold;
          }

          .subItemColor {
            background-color: #ccc80b;
            padding-left: 35px;
          }

          .floatIcon {
            float: right;
          }


      //Header, Content, Footer
      .contentColor {
        background-color: #D9D9D9;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
  }
  
        .header {
          height: 300px;
    }

          .headerPicture {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
          }

        .content {
          padding: 0px 15px 15px;
    }

          a:link {
            color: #333;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: underline;
          }
    
          a:visited {
            color: #333;
          }
    
          a:hover {
            color: #01408d;
          }
    
          a:active {
            color: #333;
          }

        .fixed {
          bottom: 0px;
          position: static;
    }

          .container {
            width: auto;
            background-color: #dfdb00;
            padding: 10px 130px;
}

            p {
              padding: 0px 60px 0px 0px;
              margin: 2px 0px 0px;
              float: left;
              font-size: 13px;
            }

            .footerLinks {
              margin-right: 30px;
              color: #333;
            }

      //Infobox
      .infoColor {
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        height: 100%;
  }
  
        a:link {
          color: #333;
          font-weight: bold;
          text-decoration: underline;
        }
  
        a:visited {
          color: #333;
        }
  
        a:hover {
          color: #01408d;
        }
  
        a:active {
          color: #333;
        }

        .infoBoxPicture {
          width: 100%;
        }

        .fa {
          color: #01408d;
        }

        .btnFacebook {
          border-radius: 20px;
          background-color: white;
          margin: 10px 0px 0px 130px;
        }

        .facebookText {
          margin: 5px 40px 0px;
        }

      .emptyBox {
        //background-color: #B3B3B3;
        background-color: rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.82);
        height: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Scss/color.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row myRowStyle">

        <!-- Logo, Search, Navbar -->
        <div class="col-md-2 navColorBack">
            <div class="picture">
                <img class="logo" src="../sunset1.jpg" alt="logo">

                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group add-on marginSearch">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>



            <div id="MainMenu">
                <div class="list-group panel">
                    <!-- First Level -->
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item navColor" data-parent="#MainMenu">Home</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item navColor" data-parent="#MainMenu">Menüpunkt2</a>
                    <a href="#demo3" class="list-group-item navColor" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Menüpunkt3<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down floatIcon"></span> </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="demo3">
                        <!-- Second Level -->
                        <a href="#SubMenu1" class="list-group-item subItemColor" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#SubMenu1">Submenü1</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü1</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü2</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü3</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü4</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü5</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü6</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü7</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="list-group-item subItemColor">Submenü8</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- First Level -->
                    <a href="#demo4" class="list-group-item navColor" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu">Kontakt</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Header, Content -->
        <div class="col-md-6 contentColor">

            <div class="header">
                <img class="headerPicture" src="../sunset1.jpg" alt="header">
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <h1>Willkommen</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod <a href="#">tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</a> aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et <a href="#">justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</a> Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                <h2>Über uns ...</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est <a href="http://www.loremipsum.de/">Lorem ipsum</a> dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod <a href="#">tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</a> aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer fixed">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <p>VorschauFirma TestSite0 e.V. - TestStraße.100 - 15640 Testland</p>
                    <br />
                    <p>Tel.: 00000 / 0000 - 0</p>
                    <p>Fax: 00000 / 0000 - 00</p><br />
                    <a href="#" class="footerLinks">E-Mail: test(at)testSeitetestBereich-Test.de</a><br />
                    <a href="#" class="footerLinks">Impressum</a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLinks">Datenschutz</a>
                    <a href="#" class="footerLinks">AGBs</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <!-- Info Box -->
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 infoColor">
            <h3>Überschrift 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <h4>Überschrift 4</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt dolore magna <a href="#">aliquyam erat</a>, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            <h5>Überschrift 5</h5>
            <img class="infoBoxPicture" src="../sunset1.jpg" alt="picture">
            <h6>Überschrift 6</h6>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            <button class="btn btnFacebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            <p class="facebookText">Besuchen Sie uns auf Facebook</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 emptyBox">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row myRowStyle">
  <!-- Logo, Search, Navbar -->
        <div class="col-md-2 navColorBack">
  <!-- Header, Content -->
        <div class="col-md-6 contentColor">
  <!-- Info Box -->
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 infoColor">
  <div class="col-md-2 emptyBox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My divs ends like this, but i forgot it to copy >.<

Comment: @CryptForce add <div class="clearfix"></div> after end of emptyBox div

Comment: @CryptForce Check Updated Answer

Answer (score 0):

The row needs to be flexed

```
.myRowStyle {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem structure, so I reccomend you make this and try to be clear and ordered:

```
<!-- Use one unique div with container-fluid -->
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Put all col divs inside a div class row -->
        <div class="row myRowStyle">


            <!-- Add your divs and what you need inside each div col -->

            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 navColorBack"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 contentColor"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 infoColor"></div>

            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 emptyBox"></div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a short example of commented:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Scss/color.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                <!-- Logo, Search, Navbar -->
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 navColorBack">
                  <div class="myRowStyle">
                    <div class="input-group add-on marginSearch">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <!-- Header, Content -->
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 contentColor">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

            </div>


            <!-- Info Box -->
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 infoColor">
                <h3>Überschrift 3</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 emptyBox">
                EmptyBox
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: @CryptForce Check my answer please